# Многостраничный сайт на webpack 4

Tags: webpack, webpack4

Изучаю вебпак 4, все примеры для одностраничных сайтов. У меня есть такая структура:

```
scr
 -views
  -main_page
   -index.html
   -main.html
   -news.html
  -modules
    -header.html
    -footer.html
 -assets
  -js
  -scss
  -img
```

Как сделать так, чтобы определённые файлы подгружались только к определнным страницам, а не которые файлы, ко всем страницам сразу?

Допустим, файл all.js подгружается ко всем страницам

Файл main_page.js только к главной странице.

У меня одна точка входа и одна точка выхода для глобального файла

```
entry: {
        app: './src/index.js',
    },
    output: {
        filename: `${PATHS.assets}js/[name].js`,
        path: PATHS.dist,
        publicPath: '/'
    },
```

И один плагин для html

```
new HtmlWebpackPlugin ({
            hash: false,
            template: `${PATHS.src}/index.html`,
            filename: './index.html'
        }),
```

Как еще расширить существующую настройку?

Нужно ли указывать несколько точек входа и плагинов для html? 
А также нужно ли в основной js файл подгружать все файлы проекта?

Comment: Не совсем понятно, что нужно автору и в чем проблема....  `Как еще расширить существующую настройку?`--- Да как душе угодно, все зависит от желания, знаний и нужд проекта....  Боюсь советов будет больше чем надо и ни одного дельного...

Comment: @Air я имел в виду, как поключить чанки? Т.е. чтобы отдельный файлы подгружались к определённым страницам, а не ко всем файлам одновременно

Comment: А что тебе мешает , импортировать нужные фалы, куда надо и когда надо... Плюс про  `require.ensure()` --- почитай...

Comment: @Air не нашел годных туториолов.. .все материалы для одностраничных сайтов. + хотелось бы это сделать по грамотному

Comment: @Air вот и решил задать вопрос, думаю - помогут знающие люди))

Comment: Вот [тут](https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/) подробнее некуда

Comment: @Air спасибо, посмотрю обязательно!